# How to do group by rollup in spring boot jpa. Want to fetch sum of object attribute along with list of objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class stock that holds two entities product and warehouse. Combination of product and warehouse will always we unique and Stock entity is used to store stock information present for every product in each warehouse.

```
@Entity
public class Stock extends ReusableFields
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Long stockId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="productId",nullable=false )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @NonNull
    Product product;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="warehouseName",nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @NonNull
    Warehouse warehouse;

    @NonNull
    Float quantityInHand;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Now, I want to fetch total stock of each product followed by detailed stock. Eg

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "productId": 22,
            "totalQuantityInHand": 50,
            "details": [
                {
                    "warehouse": "warehouse1",
                    "quantityInHand": 20
                },
                {
                    "warehouse": "warehouse2",
                    "quantityInHand": 30
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

One way I can achieve this is by fetching all records from stock, then fetching unique product ids, then looping over each productid and feeding DAO object with productid, totalquantity, and list of stock objects for that product.

I want to know if there is any better optimum solution available which can save me from writing iterations. Basically, if I had to do the same in mysql my query will be somewhat like this.

```
SELECT 
        p.product_id AS productId,
        s.warehouse_name   AS warehouseId, 
       SUM(s.quantity_in_hand) AS quantity 
FROM   stock s 
       INNER JOIN product p 
               ON p.product_id = s.product_id 
       INNER JOIN warehouse w 
               ON w.warehouse_id = s.warehouse_name 
GROUP BY productId,warehouseId
WITH ROLLUP;
```